# Database Connection Not Valid for SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have just connected my application to SQLite and managed to create it automatically if it doesn't exist.

However, the tables within aren't getting created for some reason. When I debug, it shows me this exception in various areas:

> System.Invalid Operation Exception Database connection not valid for
>   getting number of changes
>
> Database connection not valid for getting last insert rowid

This is my appconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AutoPrint" connectionString="data source.\AutoPrintDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is my DbContext:

```
public class AutoPrintDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AutoPrintDbContext() : base("AutoPrint")
        {
            if (!Database.Exists("AutoPrint"))
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AutoPrintDbContext>());
            }
        }
        public DbSet<Programs> Programs { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT:

I added an image of the exception here:

[image]

This is my Model for Programs

```
public class Programs
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Fields { get; set; }
    public string Filetype { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change connection string? Missing equal (=).

```
<add name="AutoPrint" connectionString="data source.\AutoPrintDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

to

```
<add name="AutoPrint" connectionString="data source=.\AutoPrintDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

Comment: If I add EF6 to the end, I get this error: : 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'

Comment: please only change connection string like <add name="AutoPrint" connectionString="data source=.\AutoPrintDb.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />

Comment: It still shows that the Database Connection is invalid though. However, it creates the database file without any issues but fails at the table creation

Comment: I edited my question to show an image of the exception

Comment: Did you try add  Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated(); in constructor AutoPrintDbContext()

Comment: Sorry I can't find those methods.

Comment: Can you post model attribute for class Programs

Comment: Can you try changing from string to int  [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

Comment: I tried that as well. It doesn't work for some reason. Maybe I can't use sqlite with ef6